# Rest Accept header comma versus semicolon

Tags: rest, restsharp

I'm trying to understand the difference between using a comma versus semicolon to delimited multiple content type in one string added to the restSharp request header.

Example:

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", acceptContentType);
```

with acceptContentType being the following:

> application/json;odata=verbose

(this works as expected)

> application/json,odata=verbose

(fails with code 400: The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "application/json,odata=verbose" could not be parsed.)

and

> application/json;application/xml

(this fails with code 400. error: The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "application/json;application/xml" could not be parsed.)

> application/json,application/xml

(this returns data content type as json

> application/xml,application/json

(this returns data content type as xml

Is there a standard to follow or is it all dependant on the server side of how it handles the incoming header?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I see where I made a mistake.
swagger defeintion will look like this

> "produces": [
>             "application/json;odata=verbose",
>             "application/xml"
>       ],

and not

> "produces": [
>             "application/json",
>             "odata=verbose",
>             "application/xml"
>           ]

so comma should be the separator between types and semicolon for extending the type

> application/json;odata=verbose,application/xml

Answer (score 0):

One is media types Group, separated by comma, like application/json,application/xml
Another is Parameters Group, like odata=verbose,odata2=verbose2
if put 2 together, then will be like application/json,application/xml;odata=verbose,odata2=verbose2